How can a C# class inherit from a base class and an interface and have both classes' interfaces resolved by IOC?
This is all quickly typed pseudo code to illustrate the problem.  I have a base class that implements an interface.  I then inherit that class in two child classes which implement their own interfaces.  Finally, I inject one of the child classes into a controller.
My hope was that I could call the Delete and GetSearches methods of the base class as well as the GetCustomerSearchResults method of the child class.  But that doesn't compile.  So, apparently the base class interface can't be found even though the child class inherits from the class implementing that interface.
How else could I do this to keep the more generic find, save, delete methods in a base class while having more specific entity type methods in the child class and have both interface methods available in the controller?  Is there a certain design pattern that works well for this?
public interface ISearchService{
    Task<List<Search>> GetSearches(int userId);
    Task DeleteSearch(int id);
}

public class SearchService : ISearchService {
    private IRepository _repository;

    public SearchService(IRepository repository){
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<List<Search>> GetSearches(int userId){
        return await _repository.GetUserSearches(userId);
    }

    public async Task DeleteSearch(int id){
        await _repository.DeleteSearch(id);
    }
}


public interface ISalesSearchService{
    Task<SearchResultReport> GetSalesSearchResults(Search search);
}

public class SalesSearchService : SearchService, ISalesSearchService{

    public ISalesSearchRepository _salesRepository;
    public SalesSearchService(IRepository repository, ISalesSearchRepository salesRepository) : base(repository){   
        _salesRepository = salesRepository;
    }

    public async Task<SearchResultReport> GetSalesSearchResults(Search search){
        return _salesRepository.GetSalesSearchResults(search);
    }
}


public interface ICustomerSearchService{
    Task<SearchResultReport> GetCustomerSearchResults(Search search);
}

public class CustomerSearchService : SearchService, ISalesSearchService{

    public ICustomerSearchRepository _customerRepository;
    public SalesSearchService(IRepository repository, ICustomerSearchRepository customerRepository) : base(repository){ 
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public async Task<SearchResultReport> GetCustomerSearchResults(Search search){
        return _customerRepository.GetCustomerSearchResults(search);
    }
}

public class CustomerSearchController : Controller {

    private ICustomerSearchService _customerSearchService;

    public CustomerSearchController(ICustomerSearchService customerSearchService){
        _customerSearchService = customerSearchService;
    }

    public async Task Delete(int id){
        await _customerSearchService.Delete(1);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSearchResults(int id){
        var searches = await _customerSearchService.GetSearches(_userId);
        var search = searches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        var results = await _customerSearchService.GetCustomerSearchResults(search);
        return View(results);
    }
}


I find it a bit hard to understand the real problem, but maybe I'm overthinking it and you just need to solve it like this: public interface ICustomerSearchService : ISalesSearchService and public interface ISalesSearchService : ISearchService

Use inheritance with the interfaces.
 ICustomerSearchService : ISalesSearchService

and
 ISalesSearchService : ISearchService


Ah, I didn't even realize an interface could inherit another interface.  Thank you!

@geoffswartz Yeah, I was overthinking your question. Good that this answered it.
